# AsyncStorage is null when using with react native web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I am trying to use async storage with "react native web" but it is saying " AsyncStorage is null".

commands I ran:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage

react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage
```

When I try to open localhost:3000, it says that error.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Where does it say, asyncstorage is null? How do you improve and use it? We need a little bit more information to help you.

Comment: When I try to open localhost:3000, I got that error. I tried to fix by running link command but didnt work.

Comment: Show some code how you use it.

Comment: I only imported it because I am testing app without asyncstorage. So only one import -- import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

Comment: what is your react-native version?

Comment: My react native version is 0.55.x

Comment: In case you want to test it, you can create new app as per this repo and then try adding async storage to it. Then you can see error - https://github.com/orYoffe/create-react-native-web-app

Answer (score 1):

I think one thing you can do is use @callstack/async-storage module.

`import AsyncStorage from '@callstack/async-storage';`

According to their github repo, you can use it on web and mobile and works excellent with redux-persist.