# React native store tokens, with web, android, ios compability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, token, asyncstorage

I have search a lot on internet but I was unable to find solution. Let's say I have API. I send Login request to that API and get back a token with expiraci date and everything. I then want to store that token inside device and be able to 'call it' on every compnent... Thats not a poblem with AsyncStorage. My problem is that I need compability for: web, android, ios.

Is there some library that can do it?

Is it Possible to use AsyncStorage for: web, android and ios?

Thanks for every solution!

Sorry if this is dumb question but I am new to react native and react in general...

PS: My project is expo managed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I saw from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357415/asyncstorage-is-null-when-using-with-react-native-web) that you can try [@callstack/async-storage](https://github.com/callstack/async-storage#readme).
In the readme, it states that it's a cross-platform async storage implementation for web and mobile</s>

**Edit**

I see that [React Native Async Storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) does support all the platforms including **web**. Documentation [here](https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage).

Comment: Hello, I have checked it but I was unable to run it on android/ios device. To my knowledge it is not compatible with newer versions of Android... But thanks

Comment: @AndrewBlack my bad. I see that React Native Async Storage does support web since V2. See my edited answer for links

Comment: Hmm thats weird, I was unable to run it in web, I will look more into it and let you know ! :D

Comment: Ok, thanks, I am able to run it in my browser and my android... From now on I will stick to their documentation, Upvote and accept. Thanks :)